# Redirect a directory to another subdomain

Tags: apache-2.2, rewrite

Im not familiar with apache2's rewrite engine so i need someone's help to create a rewrite rule.
Im trying to redirect this folder's and its content's url:
http://mysite.com/junk/

to
http://files.anotherone.com/misc/

Comment: Just to be clear, you don't redirect a folder to a URL, you redirect the URL to a folder. It's important to understand the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll forgive your apparent lack of documentation-reading because the documentation for `mod_rewrite` is pretty unreadable. Thing is, you don't need `mod_rewrite`. ([This is my favorite link](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite) for Server Fault.)

Much lighter and easier to understand if you just use `mod_redirect`:

```
Redirect /junk/ http://files.anotherone.com/misc/
```

Also, you'll want to [read the fine documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html) on `.htaccess` files, particularly the part that says

> You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a `Directory` block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a simple .htaccess rewrite like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://files.anotherone.com/misc/$1 [R=301]
```

This should be placed under the .htaccess file located in the /junk directory of mysite.com